# Les mots composés de Nom + -iste

Tags: étymologie, noms-propres, suffixes

> *Les plus anciens termes en -iste ou –ien dans la langue française remontent aux guerres de religion, avec les Papistes, les Calvinistes,
>   les Luthériens", explique Marc Arabyan. "Les termes en **–iste** sont
>   des termes de guerre, le -ien désignant la paix." Les suffixes -iste,
>   et **-ien** renvoient à deux états différents. L’un (comme
>   "macroniste")  violent, en mouvement, en conquête, tout en engagement
>   ; l’autre ("macronien"), c’est l’état apaisé, établi, plus stable.*
>
> D'après  [lci.fr](https://www.lci.fr/elections/en-marche-les-partisans-d-emmanuel-macron-sont-ils-des-macronistes-ou-des-macroniens-attention-cela-ne-veut-pas-dire-la-meme-chose-2051733.html)

---

1) L'article dit-il vrai sur l'emploi du suffixe -ien et les explications fournies sur sa non utilisation avec les noms Hollande et Sarkozy ?

2) En français est-il correct d'employer les termes tel que Juppéiste par exemple ?
Car il serait difficile de tous les référencer dans les dictionnaires. Pouvons nous donc les utiliser à l'écrit sans que ce soit une faute ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

L'article est globalement correct, mais le passage que vous mettez en exergue pourrait peut-être être nuancé:

- le suffixe en -iste se réfère généralement à l'idéologie ou ligne politique de la personne. Il y a d'ailleurs souvent un substantif équivalent en -isme (ex: les *macronistes* sont partisans du *macronisme*)
- le suffixe en -ien est plus neutre, et peut simplement qualifier ce qui est associé à la personne, sans connotation idéologique

Tous les hommes politiques n'ont pas droit aux deux termes, mais si le doublon existe, on constate bien la différence, avec l'exemple parlant de De Gaulle:

- *Gaullien* se réfère à sa personne (et plus largement, à ce qui a été fondé sous sa présidence, ou tout simplement à son époque): la [période *gaulienne*](https://www.universalis.fr/encyclopedie/cinquieme-republique-la-periode-gaullienne-1958-1969/)
- *Gaulliste* se réfère à la tendance politique héritée de De Gaulle, donc au *gaullisme*: le *parti gaulliste*. Nombre de politiciens français se diront fièrement *gaullistes* sans que cela ne porte une connotation de guerre ou de violence.

Par contre, l'affirmation que *hollandiste n'a jamais vraiment existé* est discutable: une rapide recherche sur Google montrera que le terme est bien attesté, et même référencé par [Wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/hollandiste).

Quant à savoir s'il est correct de décliner tout nom d'homme politique en -iste/-isme/-ien, il n'y a pas de règle, seuls l'usage et l'euphonie comptent... *Juppéiste* est en tout cas compris et même utilisé, comme *filloniste*, *lepeniste*, *mélenchoniste*, etc. Sans avoir de données statistiques précises, il me semble néanmoins que si l'usage est très fréquent dans la vie politique française (peut-être plus encline aux grand débats idéologiques ou aux grandes figures politiques), il est moins fréquent pour les hommes politiques étrangers, où il est réservé aux personnages qui imposent une influence internationale (ex: *trumpisme*, *poutinisme* - et étant moi-même belge, j'ai du mal à trouver des exemples utilisés pour des hommes politiques belges, même dans la presse nationale francophone...).

Un autre article sur le sujet [ici](https://www.francetvinfo.fr/politique/linguistique-pourquoi-parle-t-on-de-sarkozystes-et-de-hollandais_261807.html).

Comment: Dire que l'auteur *se trompe* me semble abusif. Il écrit qu'hollandiste n'a **jamais *vraiment* existé**. L'adverbe *vraiment* indique ici que l'auteur ne nie pas l'existence du mot *hollandiste* mais indique simplement qu'il ne fait pas le poids face à *hollandais*, que sa popularité est insignifiante.

Comment: Mouais... difficile à vérifier vu que *hollandais* dans un ngram donnerait un nombre énorme de résultats, mais j'ai mes doutes quant à sa prépondérance face à *hollandiste*, qui est loin d'être insignifiant: il est bel et bien utilisé par Le Monde par exemple (https://www.lemonde.fr/election-presidentielle-2017/article/2016/11/07/le-dernier-carre-des-hollandistes-flanche_5026424_4854003.html). Et les commentaires sous cet article du *Figaro* sont amusants... http://www.lefigaro.fr/politique/le-scan/coulisses/2014/04/02/25006-20140402ARTFIG00099-remaniement-la-mefiance-des-hollandais.php

Comment: Je n'avais jamais entendu ou lu hollandiste alors que le mot hollandais était souvent présent dans les médias, mais je concède que c'est forcément subjectif. Sinon, dans la même veine, en Belgique on peut trouver des **néerlandistes** ;-)

Comment: Quelques **dirupistes** aussi...

Comment: Nonnon... Greg! Rassurez-vous. Vous n'êtes pas en reste. ;-) Au fond de mes bois hexagonaux j'ai déjà vu passer une *"ligne micheliste"* un étrange (à cause des capitales) *"Di Rupiste"* ainsi que quelques *"principes De Weveriens"*... non moins curieux...

Comment: J'attends avec impatience que Paul Magnette définisse la ligne politique du *magnettisme*... Plus sérieusement,  on parle encore par exemple de nolsiste/nolsisme. Le cas de ligne *micheliste* est intéressant,  son opposée devrait être une ligne *reyndersiste* ou *reyndersienne* (du nom du rival de Michel) mais je ne pense pas que ces 2 termes existent, peut-être simplement parce que difficiles à prononcer?