# Comment les adjectifs qui se référent aux personnes sont-ils formés?

Tags: adjectifs, noms-propres, néologismes, suffixes, morphologie

En anglais, il y a des adjectifs qui sont formés par l'addition d'un suffixe à un nom tels que *kafkaesque*, *Wagnerian*, et *Trotskyite* (ou *Trotskyist*). Ces adjectifs caractérise le style des œuvres des personnes dont le nom est le radical ou le courant de pensée que l'on associe à l'œuvre ou à la carrière de ces personnes. Par exemple, *kafkaesque* décrit ce qui évoque l'atmosphère des romans de Kafka et *Wagnerian* ce qui  est conforme au style musical de Wagner.  Ce type d'adjectif existe aussi en français: il y a *kafkaïen*, *newtonien*, *rousseauiste*, *socratique*.
Par exemple, pour « kafkaïen » on extrait du TLFi « ***A**.  Qui appartient à Kafka ou caractérise ses thèmes, son style. Poétique kafkaïenne. **B.**  P. anal., souvent péj. Qui évoque l'atmosphère sinistre, absurde, dérisoire des œuvres de Kafka. ».

Comment ces adjectifs sont-ils formés? Généralement, *-en* et *-iste* sont-ils les seuls suffixes qui soient utilisés? Quelles règles les régissent?

Il me semble que l'on utilise *-iste* quand on parle d'une philosophie souvent politique qu'on suit, ou sinon *-en*. (Mais on parle des *keynésiens* et des *soréliens*.) Cette interprétation est-elle correcte?

Comment: Question similaire [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/33020/les-mots-compos%C3%A9s-de-nom-iste).

Comment: @LPH: Thanks for the corrections. I've made an attempt to clarify. It was difficult to explain it to myself succinctly and clearly even in English, so it's no surprise it didn't work out in French either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

L'ensemble des précision apportées ci-dessous à la formation des adjectifs à partir de noms de personnes est tirée du TLFi aux entrées des divers suffixes. Les suffixes ne sont pas seulement applicables à des noms de personne; des noms de dieux ont été considérés comme des noms de personne dans la source, mais pas dans le présent relevé ; cependant des noms de personnages fictifs, (Guignol, Figaro, faune…) ont été inclus.
 Les  suffixes considérés sont au nombre de quatre, dont l'un est plus exactement une famille de suffixes (**-iste, -ien, -esque, -ique**). N'ont pas été prises en compte les particularités orthographiques de connection des suffixes à leur racine.

> **1/** **-iste** Le mot résultant désigne celui qui adhère à une doctrine, une croyance, un système, un mode de vie, de pensée ou d'action, ou exprime l'appartenance à ceux-ci.

- *religion* :  bouddhiste, calviniste, lazariste,
- *politique* :  bonapartiste, gaulliste, léniniste, maoïste, marxiste

> **2/** **-ien, -ienne, -é(i)en, -é(i)enne, (-éen, -éien, -éenne, -éienne)** Cette famille de suffixes sert à exprimer l'idée d'origine ou d'appartenance. Les suffixes ont le sens de « relatif à, qui a rapport à; qui tient de ».

Les personnes sont notamment des personnalités du monde artistique, littéraire, politique ou scientifique.

- apollinarien, aristotélicien, baudelairien, cicéronien, giralducien, luthérien, mallarméen, sadien, victorien, goethéen, kafkéen (s.v. kafkaïen), linnéen, mallarméen, nietzschéen, keynésien, sorélien, etc.

***Remarque***

1. La plupart de ces adjectifs sont employés substantivement au sens de « adepte de, spécialiste de ». Quelquefois, le terme est substantivé en un sens bien déterminé, ainsi « grégorien »; il arrive par ailleurs que le terme soit seulement un substantif : « draisienne », « julienne ».
2. *Opposition*

   - **a)** *-ien/-ique* Le suffixe « -ique » ne s'accole que rarement à des noms propres et surtout pour former des adjectifs à partir de noms d'auteurs, ainsi «  aristotélique/aristotélicien  », « machiavélique/machiavélien », « platonique/platonicien  », «  sadique/sadien ».
   - **b)** *-ien/-iste*.  Le sens des suffixes « -ien » et « -iste » est différent :« -iste » accolé à un nom propre indique l'adhésion, l'appartenance à une doctrine, à une pensée élaborée par une personne dont le nom fournit la base du dérivé ; « -ien » indique ce qui est propre à un homme, ce qui lui appartient : « gaullien/gaulliste », « marxien/marxiste ». Historiquement, « -ien » a tenu le rôle de « -iste » ; ainsi « calvinien » (LITTRÉ) a disparu de la langue moderne au profit de « calviniste », mais un certain nombre de doublets subsistent sans qu'il soit possible de les différencier. D'autre part, il est souvent difficile de déterminer pourquoi l'un de ces suffixes est préféré à l'autre. Bien que « -iste » soit plus usité que « -ien » dans le vocabulaire politique, il lui cède parfois la place comme dans cet exemple : Il n'est pas de jour sans qu'un gaulliste (...) ou même un giscardien dénoncent le vide politique au pouvoir.
3. Le suffixe « -ien » peut aussi s'accoler à un certain nombre de noms communs désignant une dignité ou une charge : « chérifien », « pharaonien », « régalien », « tsarien ». On retrouve le plus souvent pour ces termes les oppositions signalées supra souvent pertinentes au plan sémantique : « pharaonien/pharaonique », « régalien/régaliste », « tsarien*/tsariste ».

> **3/** **-ique**

Ce suffixe est issu du latin « -icus », de sens « relatif à », « qui est propre à », formateur de très nombreux adjectifs épicènes parfois employés substantivement et appartenant notamment au vocabulaire scientifique et technique.

- sadique, botticellique, bouddhique, marotique, méphistophélique, narcissique, ossianique.

***Remarque*** L'adjectif en -ique, en emploi substantif féminin, entre parfois en concurrence avec le substantif masculin en -isme correspondant :  « eugénique » (subst. fém.)/« eugénisme » (subst. masc.).

> **4/** **-esque**

Ce suffixe est formateur d'adjectifs dérivés de noms communs de personnes et de noms propres de personnes et qui indiquent une ressemblance, une manière d'être ou d'agir dont on accuse l'originalité dans un sens plus ou moins péjoratif ou laudatif.

**A.** Le mot de base est un nom commun ou un syntagme complet

**a)** Le nom désigne une personne d'une nature peu ordinaire ou propre à l'ironie ou à la caricature.

- juponesque (propre aux jupons, aux femmes); ex : Ma négligence (...) que vous (...) attribuez à des causes juponesques »
- mirlitonesque (propre à un mirliton); ex : essaya un début mirlitonesque

**b)**.Le nom désigne une personne, un type de personne souvent doué d'un trait caractéristique, comique ou très original

- dandyesque
- bellemeresque   (propre aux belles-mères); ex :La manière de traiter la terrible gent bellemeresque
- bouffonesque   (digne d'un bouffon); ex : Plagiaires aussi de l'empire, les Espagnols empruntèrent le nom de bataillon sacré à la retraite de Moscou, ainsi qu'ils étaient bouffonesques de la Marseillaise, des sanculotides
- pachalesque  (digne d'un pacha); ex : Une existence pachalesque
- paysanesque  (qui concerne les paysans); ex : Cette vie entièrement paysanesque
- pharaonesque  (digne d'un pharaon); ex : Une maison pharaonesque
- pioupiesque, pioupioutesque (qui tient du pioupiou); ex : Ithyphalliques et pioupiesques Leurs quolibets l'ont dépravé!
- ratichon(n)esque   (propre au ratichon, au prêtre);
- ruffianesque  (digne d'un ruffian); ex : Ses façons chattes et ruffianesques
- satyresque (digne d'un satyre); ex : Je ne sais quel air satyresque qui relevait son propos
- sultanesque (digne d'un sultan); ex : Kally-Adèle m'a mis des papillotes de ses mains de quinze ans. N'est-ce pas sultanesque? 
  tailoresque (digne d'un "tailor"); ex : Fashionable et tailoresque
- troubadouresque. (digne des troubadours); ex :  La pose troubadouresque avait été compromise par la recherche d'un lorgnon

**B**. Le mot de base est un nom propre évoquant une personne dont on souligne l'originalité dans une visée souvent péjorative

**En parlant de personnages remarquables du monde de l'art ou de la politique**

- aristophanesque (dans le genre d'Aristophane, de ses comédies); ex :  Il est question de l'intérieur aristophanesque
- baudelairesque (semblable au génie, aux goûts de Baudelaire); ex : Des amours baudelairesques, des amours avec une femme ventriloque
- bonapartesque (à la manière de Bonaparte); ex : Dans sa précision quasi bonapartesque
- carrachesque (à la manière de Carrache); ex : Comment se fait-il que ce détestable style, mou, carrachesque, ait prévalu?
- chardinesque (dans le style de Chardin); ex : L'intérieur est resté provincial, normand, « chardinesque »
- chateaubrianesque (à la manière de Chateaubriand); ex : Les réflexions chateaubrianesques sur la fuite des jours, la chute des feuilles et celle des cheveux
- eiffelesque (dans le style d'Eiffel); ex : Inouï (...) Eiffelesque
- gionesque (dans le style de Giono); ex : Dîner gionesque
- giottesque (dans le style de Giotto); ex : Les spectateurs habitués aux conventions de l'école giottesque
- gobinesque (dans le genre de Gobineau); ex : Tout le reste de son sang était allemand pur jus, et gobinesque à ravir
- goyesque (dans le style de Goya); ex : Quelque formule d'art goyesque
- hoffmannesque (à la manière d'Hoffmann); ex : L'idée vague et hoffmannesque que mon ignorance se formait de celui-ci
- ingresque (dans le style d'Ingres); ex : Un effet ingresque
- julesvernesque (à la manière de Jules Verne); ex : Cette tour a quelque chose d'impressionnant, de julesvernesque, un aspect de machine à visiter la lune
- juvénalesque (dans le style de Juvénal); ex : Tant de poésies juvénalesques
- labruyéresque.  (dans le style de La Bruyère); ex : Cela prendra facilement un facile tour « labruyéresque »
- léonardesque (dans le style de Léonard de Vinci); ex : Des mouvements d'une grâce tout à fait léonardesque
- louisquatorzesque (à la manière de Louis XIV); ex : C'est pas pour deux sous louisquatorzesque!
- marinesque (dans le style de Marino); ex : En style marinesque
- martialesque (dans le style de Martial); ex :  Des épigrammes martialesques
- michel-angesque, michelangelesque (dans le style de Michel-Ange); ex : Une vigueur toute michel-angesque. La mort de Nana est « michelangelesque »
- moliéresque (dans le genre de Molière); ex :  Une poursuite moliéresque
- montaignesque(à la manière de Montaigne); ex :  Type que je suis heureux d'avoir qualifié de montaignesque
- moréesque (à la manière de Moréas); ex : Qu'est-ce encore que ce festin moréesque?
- ossianesque (dans le style d'Ossian); ex : Les froides statues de l'école davidienne s'enveloppèrent de brumes ossianesques
- paganinesque (à la manière de Paganini); ex : Le tour de force paganinesque de Sivori
- péruginesque (dans le style de Pérugin); ex : Raphaël est resté péruginesque toute sa vie
- pétrarchesque (à la manière de Pétrarque); ex :La logique pétrarchesque de « l'Héloïse »
- poussinesque (dans le style de Poussin); ex : Un sens poussinesque de la composition
- raphaëlesque (à la manière de Raphaël); ex : dans cette Rome aimable et raphaëlesque de Léon X
- rembranesque (dans le style de Rembrandt); ex :  Une façon toute rembranesque
- sardanapalesque (à la manière de Sardanapale); ex : Ce souper sardanapalesque
- scarronesque (dans le genre de Scarron); ex : La lie un peu scarronesque où Molière trempa au début
- schumannesque (dans le style de Schumann); ex : Le dernier morceau (inquiet, tourmenté, schumannesque)
- scipionesque (à la manière de Scipion); ex : Une retenue scipionesque
- tabarinesque (à la manière de Tabarin); ex : À ce degré de farce tabarinesque
- titiannesque (dans le style du Titien); ex : Une tête chauve d'une couleur titiannesque
- tubalcaïnesque (à la manière de Tubal-Caïn); ex : Ce tubalcaïnesque Palais des Machines de notre quatre-vingt-neuf.

  **En parlant de héros légendaires ou popularisés par le théâtre, le cinéma ou le roman**
- bergottesque (à la manière de Bergotte, héros de Proust); ex : Il userait non des phrases propres à convaincre les juges, mais de ces phrases bergottesques que son tempérament littéraire particulier lui suggérait naturellement
- caligaresque (à la manière du Docteur Caligari, héros d'un film d'épouvante); ex : Avec les essais caligaresques du Français Robert Florey
- diafoiresque (à la manière de T. Diafoirus, héros du Malade imaginaire); ex : Une scène « diafoiresque », où l'on examinait le fond d'un pot de chambre
- don juanesque (à la manière de Don Juan); ex : Une foule d'aventures don juanesques
- eupalinesque (à la manière d'Eupalinos, héros de Valéry); ex : Une espèce de chose eupalinesque
- figaresque (à la manière de Figaro); ex : Le jurisprudent figaresque
- gargantualesque (à la manière de Gargantua); ex : Ce tournebroche gargantualesque
- guignolesque (à la manière de Guignol); ex : Les pages colériques, guignolesques et truculentes de la Correspondance [de Flaubert]
- polichinellesque (à la manière de polichinelle); ex : Une voix un rien « polichinellesque »
- rolandesque (à la manière de Roland); ex : Très espagnol et rolandesque
  sherlockholmesque (à la manière de Sherlock Holmes); ex : Mes talents sherlockholmesques
- tartarinesque (à la manière de Tartarin); ex : Dans les tempéraments à tendance mythomaniaque, de type tartarinesque

  **CONCURRENCE DU SUFFIXE**

**i/** *Avec « -ien »*  En général, « -ien » dénote le génie, le style personnel d'œuvres, d'hommes illustres ou notoires; c'est un suffixe essentiellement laudatif;

- appollinien, aragonien, berliozien, érasmien, grahamgreenien, honeggerien, julesvernien, mozartien, puccinien, verdien.

  Au contraire, « -esque » révèle et accentue l'originalité sinon l'étrangeté de ces créateurs ou de ces créations : on peut admettre par exemple que « hugolien » évoque le poète-mage, le penseur, et « hugolesque » ridiculise la démesure, la luxuriance de son œuvre. De la même manière, « chaplinien » s'opposerait à chaplinesque, « julesvernien » à  « julesvernesque », etc. Il n'en reste pas moins que l'un et l'autre de ces suffixes sont souvent employés sans intention particularisante et que l'interprétation reste au choix du lecteur.

**ii/** *Avec « -ique »*   On peut noter que « faunique » se réfère à la faune et que « faunesque » se rapporte au faune de la mythologie.